# Why does "one half" have no hyphen, but "two-thirds" does?

Tags: hyphenation, fractions

I often see the fraction ⅔ written with a hyphen, but I never see ½ written with one.  Is it correct to have the hyphen in *two-thirds*, and if so why don't we write *one-half*?

Comment: +1. "One half" often *is* written with a hyphen -- [a Google search for "one half" on NYTimes.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:nytimes.com+%22one+half%22) finds plenty of instances with a hyphen and plenty of instances with a space -- but the frequency difference is interesting nonetheless.

Comment: Maybe people are so used to seeing "a half" without a hyphen that they (incorrectly) leave it out of "one-half".

Comment: @ruakh It looks from your results that NYT does mandate 'one-half' when it refers to a number, but there are a lot of instances of 'one half *of* something' which wouldn't take a hyphen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Chicago Manual of Style has these guidelines:

> For compounds formed with fractions:
>
> - The noun form is **open** (a *half hour*)
> - The adjective form is **hyphenated** (a *half-hour* session)
>
> For simple fractions:
>
> - **Hyphenated** in noun, adjective, and adverb forms, except when second element is already hyphenated (*one-half*; *one and three-quarters*;
>     *one twenty-fifth*)

So "1/2" should always be written out as *one-half*. (Unless it's in a sentence like "one half of a perfect pair," in which case it's not a fraction.)

Answer (score 4):

One half need not be hyphenated when used as a noun; however, it must be hyphenated when used as an adjective:

```
 1. I am entitled to one half of the pizza.
 2. I have a one-half interest in the pizza.
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your answer, but an answer citing a source gives the same rule. (Admittedly, it does not supply examples).

Answer (score 2):

It is correct to have the hyphen. I am not quite sure why the people that you see write "one half" do not write "one-half" but they should!

Searching for "one half" at dictionary.reference.com does not return any results, but searching for "one-half" does.

[One-half dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/one-half?s=t)

This is the same for "two-thirds".

[Two-thirds dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/two-thirds?s=ts)

Answer (score 1):

This made me think of when you write a check: "One hundred and twenty-two..." but there is no hyphen in the first portion.  See [Grammarly](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/punctuation/hyphen/11/hyphen-in-compound-numbers/) for examples of when to hyphenate: "When writing a compound number...we use a hyphen in between them. This applies to any number between 21 and 99. Numbers higher than ninety-nine don’t require a hyphen.  This rule applies even if these numbers are preceded by other numbers.  The rule also applies if a number between 21 and 99 is being used as an adjective."

Comment: Sorry...since this question was already answered, I meant to post this as a comment to another answer but had it down in the "answer" section while I edited it.  I guess I'll leave it where it is.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with adding an additional answer to an already 'accepted' question, so long as with your addition the question as a whole is a better resource.